# how to identify and merge the messages of different queues in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Background:
We had previously used hibernate search, Lucene and jboss hornetq queue for indexing.

Our Application is the producer and sends the metadata(unique data information to identify a record in the Database) to the hornetq.
Consumer receives this metadata and query against the database to fetch the complete record details(including child objects).
This is much more database centric approach.

Now we want to eliminate the database centric approach for indexing. We have decided to use kafka rather hornetq.

There is no issue when user creates the data.

We see there is a potential problem when the user edits the data(Say a parent entity with two child objects). When the data is pulled from the database for user display,
we push the same data to kafka topic1. When user modify's the data(say parenet level data) and submits. We get only the parent level data(don't get the child objects data), we push the changed data to topic2. Now we have to merge the message present in topic1(child objects) with the corresponding message in topic2(parent level data)

Note: We have to take this route as you know there is no update in Indexing rather it is delete and then insert.

Questions:

1. If i go with the above approach, how can I map the specific
   message present in topic1 with the specific message in topic2. Is
   there a way to provide the same message ids in topic1 and topic2?
2. Is there any way to resolve this issue if i use the single topic?
3. Is there any better design/approach to resolve the above issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. If i go with the above approach, how can I map the specific message present in topic1 with the specific message in topic2. Is there a way to provide the same message ids in topic1 and topic2 ?

To map or join the specific messages between topics in the same Kafka cluster maybe Kafka Stream and KSQL is a good direction to do. Can you find the reference [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-real-time-streaming-etl-from-oracle-transactional-data).

There are many ways to make an object unique and I suggest using parent entity id when you send messages to topic1 and topic2. Sample Java code as following:

```
ProducerRecord<String, ParentEntity> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic1, 
ParentEntity.getId(), ParentEntity);
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, ParentEntity>> future = 
kafkaTemplate.send(record);
future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, 
ParentEntity>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, ParentEntity> result) {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        //print out error log 
    }
});

ProducerRecord<String, ChildEntity> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic2, 
ChildEntity.getParentEntityId(), ChildEntity);
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, ChildEntity>> future = 
kafkaTemplate.send(record);
future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, 
ChildEntity>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, ChildEntity> result) {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        //print out error log 
    }
});
```

> 2. Is there any way to resolve this issue if i use the single topic ?

You can create a new table (said A) in database to store the full message to be sent for indexing. Every time user creates or updates data the message also to be inserted/updated to the table A. Finally your Kafka client pulls message objects from the table A and produce to an unique topic in Kafka cluster.

> 3. Is there any better design/approach to resolve the above issue ?

Can you try Kafka Stream and KSQL as I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will try your solution and let you know later